# JSON Web token(JWT) as API key in analytics service

Tags: json, session, server, api-key, jwt

We are running analytics service for web. Each application created inside the service is provided with the script and `API key` to collect the metrics. Users have to copy the script into their HTML to monitor the site. The `API key` is public and anyone can see it from HTML code. So anyone can use the API key to send fake data into account.

We heard that JSON Web token(`JWT`) is a better way to replace session cookies. Will JWT can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, such a code snippet must be inside the HTML code. In that sense it makes no difference whether you use an API key or a JWT token. Both can be read and used.

**But** you can embed an expiration time in the JWT token. This way, a copy/pasted JWT token out of the html page is only usable for a relatively short time.

It won't stop determined people from inserting fake data, as they can write a script to read a "fresh" JWT token by regularly downloading the html page.

So: it helps only a little bit.